# How can I edit the Axes labels on the chart to reflect a specific range of cell values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts, label

through VBA loop I'm producing separate charts (based on a template) for each row that i have on my sheet but when it produces it the axis labels on the Y axis show as 1,2,3,4,5... I want it to show the values in the cell range B2:J1. How would I go about doing that?

```
Sub Macro6()

   Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:I1").Select   

    For counter = 2 To 10
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
            "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1Education.crtx")
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$" & counter & ":$J$" & counter)
        ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Charts"
        With ActiveChart
            .HasTitle = False
            .Parent.Top = 50
            .Parent.Left = c * 100
        End With
        Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select

        c = c + 3
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: B2:J1 is not a valid range. Looks like you meant B2:J10.

Comment: Please supply some sample data and show expected output. It will be much quicker to formulate an answer.

Comment: B2:J1 is in fact a valid range, but it looks like the code starts with B2:J2, also a valid range.

Answer (score 0):

Your Set Source Data indicates only a single row, so you are not providing axis labels. I suspect your axis labels are in B1:J1, since you start making charts using B2:J2. This might use your ranges more effectively.

```
Sub Macro6()

    Dim rX As Range, rY As Range, rChart As Range

    Set rX = Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$1:$J$1")

    For counter = 2 To 10
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate _
            "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1Education.crtx"

        Set rY = Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$" & counter & ":$J$" & counter)
        Set rChart = Union(rX, rY)

        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rChart

        ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Charts"
        With ActiveChart
            .HasTitle = False
            .Parent.Top = 50
            .Parent.Left = c * 100
        End With
        Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select

        c = c + 3
    Next counter

End Sub
```